# Add new column (mySQL) showing "grouped" values

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my table with ages.

What I want to do is add a new column to my existing table that has "buckets" of ages such as: "Less than 18", "18-24", "25-34", etc.

So, for example, if the row has the 18 as the value for the `age` column, in a new column called `age_group` the value is added as "18-24" (as a string).

I have no idea how to begin this beyond getting the unique values in the age column.

**update**Here's what I've managed to get:

```
update full_db2 set age_range = (select
      case when age >= 0 and age <= 10    then "  0 - 10"
           when age > 10 and age <= 50   then " 10+ - 50"
           when age > 50 and age <= 100  then " 50+ - 100"
           else "over 100"
      end AgeRange,
      count(*) as TotalWithinRange
   group by 1)
```

This throws an error on the `group by` line. How can I fix?

Comment: please don't do this you will hear why shortly (or should)

Comment: You can create a view to do this instead of adding new column to your table. As this is a derived column which can be calculated.

Comment: Hadn't thought of a view...okay...not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing is this:

```
SELECT age,
       CASE WHEN age < 18 THEN 'Less than 18'
            WHEN age <= 24 THEN '18-24'
            WHEN age <= 59 THEN '25-60'
                           ELSE '60+'
       END agegroup
  FROM table
```

The CASE expression will make categories of your ages.

To summarize, you'll use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       CASE WHEN age < 18 THEN 'Less than 18'
            WHEN age <= 24 THEN '18-24'
            WHEN age <= 59 THEN '25-60'
                           ELSE '60+'
       END agegroup
  FROM table
 GROUP BY agegroup
```

There's another possible way to handle this based on a separate lookup table showing the ranges you want. But that's a bit harder, and this works.

In your example, you're trying to combine a `GROUP BY` operation with an `UPDATE` operation.  You Can't Do That.™

Comment: Okay. I do need to add a new column (or update an empty one) with these new values. There has to be a way to do this.